# IPv4 ICMP Codes/Errors for WAN transmissions

Tags: cisco, redhat, wide-area-network, ipv4, icmp

Can someone tell me which IPv4 ICMP Codes/Errors i have to unlock as Best Practise for WAN transmission (RedHat und Cisco)?

Answer (score 1):

Allow error messages at a minimum. If you block error messages you'll cause timeouts because a system keeps waiting for something that will never happen and it won't know about that because the error message that would have told it that was blocked.

Things like redirects can usually be blocked, but depending on your network architecture it might cause less efficient routing.

Some people like to block echo messages (ping) but I always find that that creates confusion and complicates debugging and therefore I always require it to be on for systems on my networks.

I personally don't block ICMP messages at all, but only rate limit them.